# MPU6050 providing gyroscope values for linear acceleration

Tags: ros, imu, ekf, ros2, ros-humble

I am using [this ROS2 driver](https://github.com/hiwad-aziz/ros2_mpu6050_driver) to connect my MPU6050 to RPi 4 running ROS2 humble. It outputs an IMU message containing linear acceleration and angular velocity. The linear acceleration values seem to be gyroscope values, as they change when I tilt the robot but not when the robot accelerates in X,Y or Z. But I want X and Y acceleration values for Ros2 robot_localization via ekf, how would I get that. Is that an issue with this driver, or a problem with MPU6050? Thanks I am a beginner.

Edit: I get the values described in the robot_localization wiki:

> Acceleration: Be careful with acceleration data. The state estimation
> nodes in robot_localization assume that an IMU that is placed in its
> neutral right-side-up position on a flat surface will: Measure +9.81
> 9.81  meters per second squared for the Z Z  axis. If the sensor is rolled +90 90  degrees (left side up), the acceleration should be
> +9.81
> 9.81  meters per second squared for the Y Y  axis. If the sensor is pitched +90 90  degrees (front side down), it should read -9.81
> 9.81  meters per second squared for the X X  axis.

But I don’t understand how this works. When I pitch the robot forward, it goes forward faster and faster in RViz. And when moving around it eventually drifts because of this. Why is linear_acceleration providing me angular values? Perhaps it is measuring the acceleration forces on the robot but this would change when the robot is pitch/rolled so how does the EKF properly control for changes in pitch and roll?

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the data that convinced you that the values are not what you're expecting?

Comment: @Tully I edited my comment. I’m getting the right values but have a hard time understanding how these values are used to determine position of the robot, if pitch and roll affects these values.